# find the number b where a = b + 19% of b

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Find which number plus its **19%** gives for example *200, 233 ..*

Story short: 
for example I have the number `0.30` now I need to know with formula how can I get which **number plus its 19%** gives `0.30` ?

I know this must be simple math but I am not so good with it.

Comment: You have literally written the required equation in your title ( $19\%$ of $m$ translates to $\frac{19m}{100}$). You just need to solve for $m$ now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want $n=1.19m$, so $m=\frac n{1.19}$  For $n=0.30, m \approx 0.2521$

Comment: yes thats correct now I know I just cant accept the answer in the next 6 minutes :) thank you

Answer (score 4):

We'll let $a$ represent the "end" amount, in decimal (so $a = 0.30$ corresponds with an end amount at $30\%$ e.g.), and we'll let $b$ represents the "starting quantity" we are interested in finding (the amount we started with before adding $19\%$ to it, to get $a$). Then

$$a = b + 0.19 b = 1.19 b \iff b = \frac{a}{1.19}$$

So if we want to know what number $b$ plus $19\%$ gives $a = 2.33$ ($233\%$), then we compute

$$b = \frac{2.33}{1.19} \approx 1.9580, \;\text{ or} \;\;195.80\%$$

Comment: yes thats correct now I know I just cant accept the answer in the next 6 minutes :) thank you

Comment: Note, you can replace 0.19 and 1.19 by any decimal fraction (representing percentage), so if you want to compute $b$ (starting amount) which, adding .25 of $b$ (25%) gives $a$: then we compute $b = \dfrac{a}{1.25}$

Comment: @amWhy: It is clear to me! +1